# How to collect in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
baza_managers = BazaManager.find(:all, 
  :conditions => ["or_unit_id != ?", 1]).collect { 
      |mou| [mou.email, mou.or_unit_id]}

respondent_emails = Respondent.find(:all).collect {|r| r.email }
```

ERROR:

```
from lib/scripts/baza_sync.rb:26:in `each'
from lib/scripts/baza_sync.rb:26
```

26 line ↓

```
baza_managers.each do |moi|
  if !respondent_emails.include?(moi)
    Respondent.create(:email => moi, :user_id => 1, :respondent_group_id => moi)
  end
end
```

**ERROR I GET:**

```
undefined method `email' for ["vadasd@test.test.com", 8]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Which line does the error message point to?

Comment: We do not know on which line the error is raised, please add it. Also it could be better to rewrite a bit your code when asking question then we will be able to understand it quickly, a copy/paste code from your application is often a lot more complicated to understand and require effort from people who want to answer you (so you get less answer).

Comment: sorry, i updated my question. 26 line (baza_managers.... end) <- in this part of code  i get error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
baza_managers = BazaManager.find(:all, 
  :conditions => ["or_unit_id != ?", 1]).collect { 
      |mou| [mou.email, mou.or_unit_id]}

respondent_emails = Respondent.find(:all).collect {|r| r.email }

baza_managers.each do |moi|
  if !respondent_emails.include?(moi[0])
    Respondent.create(:email => moi[0], :user_id => 1, :respondent_group_id => moi[1])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your code with following:

```
if !respondent_emails.include?(moi[0])
  Respondent.create(:email => moi[0], :user_id => 1, :respondent_group_id => moi[1])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think there is at least one error not in the way you are using `collect` but in the logic you write on the last lines when you go through the `baza_managers` array.

With this code the condition `respondent_emails.include?(moi)` will be always false because `respondent_emails` is an array of email addresses but `moi` is an array like `["vadasd@test.test.com", 8]` so they will never match.

I think this mistake made you make an error in the line :

```
Respondent.create(:email => moi, :user_id => 1, :respondent_group_id => moi)
```

Because this line will be evaluate as (for example) :

```
Respondent.create(:email => ["vadasd@test.test.com", 8], :user_id => 1, :respondent_group_id => ["vadasd@test.test.com", 8])
```

Which is probably not what you want.

Last, I would suggest you to read [the debugger rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html), I often use debugger to figure out where and what is the problem in this kind of code and error.

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your code as follows:

```
baza_managers = BazaManager.all(:conditions => ["or_unit_id != ?", 1]).
                  collect { |mou| [mou.email, mou.or_unit_id]}

respondent_emails = Respondent.find(:all).collect {|r| r.email }

baza_managers.each do |email, unit_id|
  unless respondent_emails.include?(email)
    Respondent.create(:email => email, :user_id => 1, 
      :respondent_group_id => unit_id)
  end
end
```

This solution can be further optimized by using `OUTER JOIN` to detect missing `Respondents`

```
BazaManager.all(
  :include    => "OUTER JOIN respondents A ON baza_managers.email = A.email",
  :conditions => ["baza_managers.or_unit_id != ? AND A.id IS NULL", 1]
).each do |bm|
  Respondent.create(:email => bm.email, :respondent_group_id => bm.or_unit_id,
    :user_id => 1)
end
```

The solution can be made elegant and optimal by adding `associations` and `named_scope`.

```
class BazaManager

  has_many :respondents, :foreign_key => :email, :primary_key => :email  

  named_scope :without_respondents, :include => :respondents, 
    :conditions =>["baza_managers.or_unit_id != ? AND respondents.id IS NULL", 1]

end
```

Now the `named_scope` can be used as follows:

```
BazaManager.without_respondents.each do |bm|
  Respondent.create(:email => bm.email, :respondent_group_id => bm.or_unit_id,
    :user_id => 1)
end
```

Comment: I think this should be the better solution as it is more readable than the solution @Tudor Constantin give using index of array

Comment: I have added a 2nd solution take a look.

Comment: I have added a 3rd solition, take a look.

Comment: One question, how to make update to do? If in other database (baza_managers) admin edited some row, How i Can update in Respondent (respondent_emails) ?

Comment: This should probably goes in a new question but the answer is using ActiveRecord callback see [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) Also since the answer of @Ferou is clearly the more relevant, you may change the correct answer to this one.